# Overriding Bootstrap font in Wordpress site - other solutions not working

Tags: css, fonts, wordpress-theming, overriding, default

In my style.css I have:

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

I have changed all occurrences of font-family in bootstrap.min.css to:

```
font-family:"Open Sans",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  //"Helvetica Neue" was formerly inbetween the quotation marks//
```

It is a Wordpress site so my style.css is in the root folder, and the bootstrap css files are enqueued in the functions.php folder.

In the Chrome Devtools it says:

```
bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.7...
------
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

style.css:14
------
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, arial, sans-serif; //this line is struck through//
}
```

As far as I know the difference between double/single quotation marks shouldn't matter (I tend to use double in html and single in css).

The font-family from my own stylesheet in Devtools is not always struck through, but the font-family from bootstrap.min.css is always ticked, and always if I untick it, my website shows Open Sans instead of Helvetica Neue.

Can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong, or have any tips for overriding the Bootstrap default font? I have tried all the solutions I could find for similar problems reported on this site but none of them have worked (eg. to !important css...).

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe a caching issue with the `bootstrap.min.css` file? Try Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + R on chrome.

Comment: @nashcheez thanks but no, I've had this problem for days so it's also survived shutting down and restarting of browsers/PC :/